# Plotly: How to prevent text overlapping between traces?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I'm working with a bar chart and a scatter trace. I must show the values as text instead of using hover text. I didn't find an answer reading the documentation. Maybe you could help me!

It would be great if I could find a way to set the bars' text at the bottom of the bars.

See my code and the plot below, thanks a lot!

```
from plotly import graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

meses = ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez']  
rlzd = [335101.3, 693658.5, 335101.3, 800019, 514379, 594379, 581279, 310029, 485022, 692091, 227918]
meta = [660756.5, 658980.9, 527478.1, 800019, 603574.5, 584198.7, 590098, 571476.2, 616965.7, 676205.1, 617237.94, 613634.7]

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, column_widths=[0.85, 0.15], print_grid=True, horizontal_spacing=0.05)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
                x=meses,y = rlzd,
                text=rlzd,
                textfont=dict(size=15,color='white'),
                textposition='auto',
                name = 'Realizado',
                showlegend=True),
                row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                x=meses,y=meta,
                name='Meta',
                mode='markers+lines+text',
                text=meta,
                textfont=dict(size=13,color='black'),
                textposition="top right",
                marker_size=8,
                showlegend=True,
                line = go.scatter.Line(color="DarkBlue", dash='dot')),
                row=1, col=1)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledege there is no direct way to edit the position of the labels within the bars.
But you can easily drop the labels and use customized annotations instead to get this:

[image]

**Complete code:**

```
from plotly import graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

meses = ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez']  
rlzd = [335101.3, 693658.5, 335101.3, 800019, 514379, 594379, 581279, 310029, 485022, 692091, 227918]
meta = [660756.5, 658980.9, 527478.1, 800019, 603574.5, 584198.7, 590098, 571476.2, 616965.7, 676205.1, 617237.94, 613634.7]

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, column_widths=[0.85, 0.15], print_grid=True, horizontal_spacing=0.05)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
                x=meses,y = rlzd,
                text=rlzd,
                textfont=dict(size=15,color='rgba(0,0,0,0)'),
                textposition='outside',
                name = 'Realizado',
                showlegend=True),
                row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                x=meses,y=meta,
                name='Meta',
                mode='markers+lines+text',
                text=meta,
                textfont=dict(size=13,color='black'),
                textposition="top right",
                marker_size=8,
                showlegend=True,
                line = go.scatter.Line(color="DarkBlue", dash='dot')),
                row=1, col=1)

# you've got one more month than
# youve got elements in the list rlzd
# the following two lines takes that
# into consideration
length_diff = len(meses)-len(rlzd)
rlzd.extend(['']*length_diff)

# adds annotatoins for each month / bar
for i, m in enumerate(meses):
    fig.add_annotation(dict(font=dict(color="white",size=12),
                            #x=x_loc,
                            x=i,
                            y=0.05,
                            showarrow=False,
                            text=rlzd[i],
                            textangle=-90,
                            xref="x",
                            yref="paper"
                           ))

fig.show()
```